# Issues using Visual Studio 2015 with Visual Studio Online Git project

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have been testing the Visual Studio 2015 RC with a Visual Studio Online Git project and I've found some problems on Visual Studio. I'd like to know if somebody has some way to get rid of these issues as they are very annoying.

1. After connecting to my VSO project, open Team Explorer and clone the repository to a local folder, I go to Branches in Team Explorer. I then choose one of my remote branches, right-click it and select Checkout. Visual Studio gives me no feedback of what is going on and after the checkout is complete, the branches treeview is not updated. I must manually refresh the list.
2. I have two local branches. When I go to the Branches window, the active branch is bold. When I right-click the other branch and ask to checkout it, it keeps the first branch in bold after the checkout of the second. I must manually refresh so that the current state is reflected on the interface.
3. Visual Studio changes some files on inner obj folders. When I try to checkout another branch, it gives me an error saying there are uncommitted changes. As I don't want to commit these changes, I exclude these files so that they are not included on the commit. Visual Studio still do not allow me to checkout another branch. I then right-click each file and undo the changes. The Output window says the undo was performed but the files are still on the list of pending changes. I must manually refresh so that the list is emptied.
4. After committing some changes to the local repository, I want to push them to the remote. On Synchronization, I see on the Outgoing Commits, the local commit. I then press Push, Visual Studio pushes the changes but the list is not refreshed. Again.

These were only some of the issues I've found, when Visual Studio does not refresh the interface. This could lead to errors and misinterpretations.

Do you have any ideas on how to overcome these problems?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as #4 with the new full release of VS2015 (ie. not the RC).

Comment: #4 I'm having the same

Comment: I'm having a similar issue as #3, but even manually refreshing does not empty the Pending Changes list. I even moved the files to "Include" or "Exclude" and tried "Undo" again, but they persist even though the Output window says the Undo operation was performed.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 have been fixed since RC as far as I can tell. I'm not on VS 2015 update 1 RC and these issues no longer occur.

3 can be prevented by having a `.gitignore` when creating a new repo, Visual Studio will add a default `.gitignore` automatically.

4 has been fixed in VS 2015 RTM, at least on my machine.